# How to Configure EndPoint Security VPN in order to route some traffic to it?

Tags: mac, network, security, vpn

I'm using [EndPoint Security VPN](https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal/user/anon/page/default.psml/media-type/html?action=portlets.DCFileAction&eventSubmit_doGetdcdetails=&fileid=77603) software in order to connect to VPN. Once it's connected I can not access any webpage, but I can still connect to the Client's environment.

How do I configure my mac in order to redirect all my HTTPS HTTP traffic **not through** the VPN?